# CI/Build tool for iOS (e.g. Bitrise.io) and plist files for API Keys

Tags: ios, xcode, continuous-integration, bitrise

What I'm trying to do is pretty straightforward. I have an iOS app with its source on Github. It uses a few keys/tokens to connect to Yelp, which I key in a separate plist file that doesn't get pushed to my repo. I'm trying to setup [bitrise.io](https://www.bitrise.io) to provide automatic builds, but obvious it has no idea about the plist file with my keys.

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a few ways to solve this:

1. use environment variables instead of a plist, or generate the plist based on env vars
2. store the plist into a second repo, and git clone that as well (this requires some tweaking of the SSH key though, so that the same SSH key can be used to git clone both repos)
3. store the plist on Amazon S3 or something similar, and download from there
4. store the plist on bitrise.io directly, as a generic file (Workflow Editor -> `Code signing & Files`)

2.-4. requires the file to be downloaded - it's quite easy to do with e.g. the `File Downloader` step

Comment: These are all solid suggestions. I thought the only answer was going to be using some sort of environment variable, but I really didn't want to add that logic to my codebase. I went with option 4. Worked like a charm. Thanks so much!